# How to create a SQL cumulative query to show if has balance for a sale considering another sales for same item

Tags: sql, postgresql, cumulative-sum

Consider the `sales` table:

| sale_id | item_id | quantity | sale_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | P1 | 5 | 2023-02-18 |
| 101 | P1 | 4 | 2023-02-17 |
| 103 | B2 | 7 | 2023-02-19 |
| 104 | P1 | 1 | 2023-02-20 |

the `stock_balance` table:

| item_id | balance |
| --- | --- |
| P1 | 6 |
| B2 | 5 |

I want to create a sql query to show what sale has balance to be delivered, the older sale has priority.
This query will produce the following result

| sale_id | item_id | quantity | sale_date | balance_start | has_balance | reserved | balance_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 103 | B2 | 7 | 2023-02-19 | 5 | false | 0 | 5 |
| 101 | P1 | 4 | 2023-02-17 | 6 | true | 4 | 2 |
| 100 | P1 | 5 | 2023-02-18 | 2 | false | 0 | 2 |
| 104 | P1 | 1 | 2023-02-20 | 2 | true | 1 | 1 |

I try to create the following query

```sql
with sale_reserved as (
  SELECT 
    s1.*, 
    sb.balance as balance_start,
    CASE 
      WHEN s1.quantity <= sb.balance AND sb.balance - s1.quantity >= (
        SELECT COALESCE(SUM(s2.quantity), 0) 
        FROM sales s2 
        WHERE s2.item_id = s1.item_id AND s2.sale_date < s1.sale_date
      ) THEN s1.quantity
      ELSE 0
    END AS reserved
  FROM 
    sales s1 
    JOIN stock_balance sb ON s1.item_id = sb.item_id 
)
select 
sale_id, item_id, quantity, sale_date , balance_start, 
reserved>0 as has_balance,
reserved,
(balance_start-reserved) as balance_end 
from sale_reserved
ORDER BY item_id, sale_date;
```

this will produce:

| sale_id | item_id | quantity | sale_date | balance_start | has_balance | reserved | balance_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 103 | B2 | 7 | 2023-02-19 | 5 | false | 0 | 5 |
| 101 | P1 | 4 | 2023-02-17 | 6 | true | 4 | 2 |
| 100 | P1 | 5 | 2023-02-18 | 6 | false | 0 | 6 |
| 104 | P1 | 1 | 2023-02-20 | 6 | false | 0 | 6 |

You can see the balance start is not correct and the sale '104' has balance and show false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive `cte`:

```
with recursive cte(sale_id, item_id, m, quantity, balance_start, has_balance, reserved, balance_end) as (
   select s.sale_id, s1.item_id, s1.m, s.quantity, b.balance, b.balance >= s.quantity, 
         case when b.balance >= s.quantity then s.quantity else 0 end, 
         case when b.balance >= s.quantity then b.balance - s.quantity else b.balance end 
   from (select s.item_id, min(s.sale_date) m from sales s group by s.item_id) s1 
   join sales s on s.item_id = s1.item_id and s.sale_date = date(s1.m) 
   join stock_balance b on b.item_id = s1.item_id
   union all
   select s2.sale_id, c.item_id, s2.sale_date, s2.quantity, c.balance_end, c.balance_end >= s2.quantity, 
         case when c.balance_end >= s2.quantity then s2.quantity else 0 end, 
         case when c.balance_end >= s2.quantity then c.balance_end - s2.quantity else c.balance_end end 
   from cte c 
   cross join lateral (select s.* from sales s where s.item_id = c.item_id 
       and s.sale_date = (select min(s1.sale_date) from sales s1 where s1.item_id = c.item_id and s1.sale_date > c.m)) s2
)
select c.sale_id, c.item_id, c.quantity, c.m sale_date, c.balance_start, c.has_balance, c.reserved, c.balance_end
from cte c order by c.item_id, c.m
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/s6sStMaA)